# xampp change mysql data dir not working

Tags: mysql, xampp

so in my xampp dir `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini` when i change

```
datadir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
```

to

```
datadir="D:/xampp/mysql/data"
```

it dosent work  but when i change it

```
datadir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
```

it works , and i have the complete copy for the xampp folder from C to D

here is my entire my.ini file

```
# Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"

# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket= "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir="C:/xampp/tmp" 
datadir="D:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error="mysql_error.log"
#bind-address="127.0.0.1"


# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "D:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Answer (score 8):

To move an existing data folder:

1. Stop MySql
2. Copy the old data folder to the new location
3. Remove all database folders in the old data folder **but do not delete anything else** (keep the `mysql` folder and all the files etc.)
4. Change `datadir` entry in the config file
5. Start MySql

Comment: This doesn't specify which config file.

Comment: @Prometheus the one referenced in the question (`C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini`)

Answer (score 2):

**First keep a copy of data folder**. 
Then in `data` folder remove `ibdata*`, `ib_logfile*`, `mysql-bin.index`, `mysql-bin.000001`, `mysql-bin.000002`, etc.

**DONT REMOVE ANY FOLDER.**

Try starting mysql server then.

Also provide us the log file(`mysql_error.log` i guess), so that we can dig in more.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the future... For me following worked fine:

- simlpy move whole xampp directory to where you like
- go into xampp root folder and execute setup_xampp.bat

The script automatically changes all configuration files and I could then `startup Apache, MySQL and Mercury` - and also connect to the local database using a client (`HeidiSQL`)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question: ONLY the datadir of the database (where the database stores data) is desired to be moved

Answer (score -1):

Copy mysql folder from xampp/mysql/data to new data directory then start mysql.
so it will get mysql user exist in tables.